# React Router Tutorial Updating Contacts with FormData not refreshing details page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new to React and React Router, so I'm currently working through the [React Router Tutorial](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial) for v6 and have got to the [Updating Contacts with Form Data](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial#updating-contacts-with-formdata) section, which is resulting in the details part of the page (right hand side) not updating and the default "No Name" being displayed when clicking on the names on the left hand side. The tutorial itself doesn't seem to have the full code anywhere that I can find, it just walks you through steps, so I cannot check that the code I have is correct.

I have followed the tutorial as fully as I can twice now, with the same result of not seeing the updated details shown in the details pane. Below are my versions of the two files that are required to be edited:
src/routes/edit.jsx:

```
import { Form, useLoaderData, redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { updateContact } from "../contacts";

export async function action({ request, params}) {
    const formData = await request.formData();
    const updates = Object.fromEntries(formData);
    await updateContact(params.contactId, updates);
    return redirect(`/contacts/${params.contactId}`);
}
```

and src/main.jsx:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
} from "react-router-dom";
import "./index.css";
import ErrorPage from "./error-page";
import Contact, { loader as contactLoader } from "./routes/contact";
import Root, { loader as rootLoader, action as rootAction } from "./routes/root";
import EditContact, { action as editAction } from "./routes/edit";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <Root />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    loader: rootLoader,
    action: rootAction,
    children: [
      {
        path:"contacts/:contactId",
        element: <Contact />,
        loader: contactLoader,
      },
      {
        path:"contacts/:contactId/edit",
        element: <EditContact />,
        loader: contactLoader,
        action: editAction,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

For reference, the React code in the root.jsx is simply an Outlet in a div:

```
<div id="detail">
  <Outlet />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pure speculation with the given info you have provided so far.

Everything seems to be right (especially `src/routes/edit.jsx`  and `src/main.jsx`. However, it does seem very weird that your `src/routes/root.jsx` only has a few lines. So here's something you can try and see if it fixes the current progress you are stuck on --

1. Complete the `src/routes/root.jsx` with the code in the following section, which is a few more sections prior to the one you linked to (Updating Contacts with FormData)  https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial#loading-data
2. Double-check your `src/contacts.js` and see if everything is copied/pasted correctly from the file provided by official documentation. (direct link to script https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ryanflorence/1e7f5d3344c0db4a8394292c157cd305/raw/f7ff21e9ae7ffd55bfaaaf320e09c6a08a8a6611/contacts.js)

Lastly, here is an example 95% followed the tutorial in CodeSandbox, so you can do direct comparison on what you have so far https://codesandbox.io/s/contact-app-by-react-router-v6-e6q7do?file=/src/routes/Root.jsx

Comment: Thanks for the help Taiwei. I have finally figured out the problem, which looks to not work in the version in the documentation, but I found the difference from your codesandbox code. FYI, in src/routes/contact.jsx, the return of the loader function is `return { contact };`, whereas just using `return contact;` worked. Thanks for your help!